# No hint path defined for [notifications]?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

No hint path defined for [notifications]? When I reset the password I get this error. I have any templates in view directory, but if auth in view - mail sending, but if auth in view/Template/ directory I get the error:

```
in FileViewFinder.php (line 112)
at FileViewFinder->parseNamespaceSegments('notifications::email')in FileViewFinder.php (line 90)
at FileViewFinder->findNamespacedView('notifications::email')in FileViewFinder.php (line 76)
at FileViewFinder->find('notifications::email')in Factory.php (line 129)
at Factory->make('notifications::email', array('level' => 'info', 'subject' => null, 'greeting' => null, 'salutation' => null, 'introLines' => array('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'), 'outroLines' => array('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'), 'actionText' => 'Reset Password', 'actionUrl' => 'http://laravel.******.pw/password/reset?4d8a6e1cd764c6c7638fb7eee784cd3394432622b296493f5ee5b39a56712182'))in Markdown.php (line 62)
```

Comment: You probably want `notifications.email`, not `notifications:email`.

Comment: Are you extending the `FileViewFinder` somewhere? If so, please show us that code.

Comment: No, im not extending. How can I do it?

Comment: ceejayoz, but if in view directory working. But if view/Template/ not working.

Comment: @РодионЛарин If it's in `views/Template` you need to do `Template.notifications.email`. It's all a folder structure - `notifications.email` means `views/notifications/email.blade.php`.

Comment: ceejayoz, yes, but where i can find notifications.email string? I search in app and view dirs - nothink.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 10, the mailmessages.php file causes the same error on line 36.
public $markdown = 'notifications:email'; When changed to , the mail notification worked.

```
File :
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage.php
line 36 :public $markdown = 'notifications:email';

change -> notifications.email
```